# A 2D Layout Algorithm for Small, Sparse, and Undirected Graphs with a Specific Edge Length

Tags: graphs, reference-request, graph-drawing

I would like to to draw a graph where every edge $e_m$ has a predefined length of $l$. Given that the graph is small and sparse, it should be feasable. However, I did not manage to find an algorithm which does this (or one that is suitable to modify) yet I'm sure that this is a solved problem. Does anyone know of such a layout algorithm and could point me to an implementation or paper?

Comment: Unless you provide more constraints, I think it's unlikely to be "solved", since it's easy to find instances for which no solution exists -- e.g., the complete graph on 4 vertices.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah, that indeed is a problem. However, as I'm dealing with sparse graphs, this problem is unlikely to happen (and if it does, the constraint can be dropped after n iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Planar Embeddings of Graphs with Specified Edge Lengths"](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/PlanarEmbedding_JGAA/paper.pdf) by Cabello, Demaine, and Rote (or one of the references they cite) seems to solve your problem.

If you don't care about edges crossing too much, a simple heuristic approach could be gradient descent. Start with a random position and iteratively wiggle the nodes a bit to decrease the sum of differences of the current edge lengths to your desired lengths.

Comment: That's it. I was playing around with a gradient descent approach, however, the edge crossings were the reason I abandoned it.